# Is SQL Server Management Studio necessary to use SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have this project in Visual C# where I use a SQL Server database, while I was working on the project I used SQL Server Management Studio to create and manage the "X" database.

And now I want to use the result program on another PCs (with the database), when I searched, I found that I need to install the SSMS on the target PCs to use the "X" database.

So, is there any other way to use the program and the database on other PCs without installing SSMS, I want to make a small installer for the program that can be installed by any one on any PC.

And thanks for reading.

Comment: Asking if you need the SSMS for using SQL Server is like asking if you need Visual Studio for running a .NET application.

Comment: i need answers, please!!

Comment: Is it "neccessary"? No. Is it useful? Yes. @CamiloTerevinto point is valid. You don't need Visual Studio to build a .Net application. You *could* do the whole thing in Notepad(++), or even a command line text editor like `nano`; if you were really that way inclined...

Comment: No.   You can connect into a remote SQL Database without having a local Server.  The Net (Microsoft Visual Studio) has library System.Data.SQLClient which can be used to connect to a remote server.  Visual Studio has a driver that makes the remote connection.  So you need a driver that allow remote connections.   Excel/Access also have libraries that have drivers to make the remote connection.

Comment: thanks for answers, BUT is it neccessary for the server to use SSMS?

Comment: The server doesn't use SSMS, you can use SSMS to connect to the server. Windows doesn't need Office to run, Office runs on Windows

Comment: i have the database detached from the current server using SSMS, on a new computer, what i need to create a local server and attach the database to use it from my program (from the same new computer ), :)

Comment: Use SSMS on the other instance and attach it, use `sqlcmd` to do it. Use Azure Data Studio.

Comment: Thanks for every one for helping , @marc_s write your comment in the ansewers part to make it the CHOSEN ONE, :p

Comment: @Larnu, thank very much for your time,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a SQL Server database on a PC, you must install the SQL Server **database engine** on that PC (or have it available somewhere in the network which can be reached from that PC).

But installing SQL Server Management Studio is **definitely NOT** a requirement. SSMS is a very useful tool and can help you do things easier - but just to have an application run against your SQL Server database, it is **NOT** needed.

There's always the option of using the command line with `sqlcmd`, or another tool in place of SSMS - but again, those are just needed for "support" and maintenance work - not for the day-to-day operation of your application.

If you found this mentioned somewhere on the internet, that site is just plain wrong.